# FileOutputStream (Apachhe POI) taking too long time to save

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx, fileoutputstream

When I am edit a .xlsx file using Apache poi, its taking too long to save. The .xlsx file contains, formulas formatting and freeze pane. I am using the following code,

```
try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            XSSFWorkbook fWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet fSheet = fWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

            for(int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++){
                if(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, index1).equals("1")){
                    XSSFCell cell = fSheet.getRow(i+1).getCell(index1);
                    cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                    cell.setCellValue(new Double(1));
                    XSSFCellStyle cs = fWorkbook.createCellStyle();
                    cs.setDataFormat(fWorkbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy"));
                    cell =fSheet.getRow(i+1).getCell(index2);
                    cell.setCellValue(new Date());
                    cell.setCellStyle(cs);
                }
            }
            file.close();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
            fWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data saved successfully.");
            parent.removeContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Edit 1:**

The excel file: http://ge.tt/5orGWSJ2/v/0?c

Loading Data into JTable from Excel:

```
try {
                FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(new File("c:\\sample.xlsx"));
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file1);
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                int rowc=sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
                int colc=sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
                Object heading[] = new Object[colc+1];
                XSSFRow row1 = sheet.getRow(0);
                for(int i=0, column =0; i < colc; i++){
                    if(i == 1){
                        heading[column++] = "";
                    }
                    heading[column++] = cellToString(row1.getCell(i));
                }
                Object [][]j=new Object[rowc-1][colc+1];

                for (int i = 1; i < rowc; i++) {
                    row1 = sheet.getRow(i); 
                    for (int jj = 0, column = 0; jj < colc; jj++) {
                        if(column == 1){
                            j[i-1][column++] = new Boolean(false);
                            j[i-1][column] = cellToString(row1.getCell(jj));
                        }
                        else{
                            j[i-1][column]=cellToString(row1.getCell(jj));
                        }
                        column++;
                    }
                }

                jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(j, heading){
                    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                        if(columnIndex == 0){
                            return java.lang.Integer.class;
                        }
                        else if(columnIndex == 1){
                            return java.lang.Boolean.class;
                        }
                        else{
                            return java.lang.Object.class;
                        }
                    }
                });

                jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(60);
                jTable1.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
                jTable1.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(BarcodePrint.this, ex);
            }
```

Writing data into excel after editing column BarcodePrint:

```
try {   
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("c:\\sample.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook fWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFCellStyle cs = fWorkbook.createCellStyle();
            cs.setDataFormat(fWorkbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy"));
            Date currentdate = new Date();
            XSSFSheet fsheet = fWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Double barcodeprintstatus = new Double(1);
            int newindex = 24;
            int printdate = 26;
            int uniqueid = 27;  
            for(int i = 0; i < jTable1.getModel().getRowCount(); i++){
                if(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, newindex).equals("1")){
                    for(int k=1; k < fsheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); k++){
                        XSSFCell cell = fsheet.getRow(k).getCell(uniqueid-1);
                        String uid = cell.getRawValue();
                        if(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, uniqueid).toString().equals(uid)){
                            cell = (fsheet.getRow(i+1)).getCell(newindex-1);
                            cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                            cell.setCellValue(barcodeprintstatus);
                            cell = fsheet.getRow(i+1).getCell(printdate-1);
                            cell.setCellValue(currentdate);
                            cell.setCellStyle(cs);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            file.close();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("c:\\sample.xlsx");
            fWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream); // this is taking so much of time. Approximately 1 min. 
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am unable to solve this problem. `fWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream);` is taking so much of time as I mentioned above. Please help. Is there any other way to save the excel file? Or can I write data partially for a single column rather than the hole workbook?

Comment: After some sort of trial and error I found that, fWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream); is taking all this time. Is there  any way to minimize it?

Comment: You are trying to save whole sheet. If you want to save only selected rows then you should save only selected rows rather than whole sheet. This would lower the time and resource consumption.

Comment: The file I am using to edit is only of 325KB and it contains  only 12 rows with 50 columns. And its taking approximately 39s.

Comment: Try creating one data format and one cell style before the for loop, and applying the same cell style to the cell inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to improve the code.

You call `fSheet.getRow(i+1)` twice. Try to introduce a variable and reuse the row rather than obtain it.

```
cell.setCellValue(new Double(1));
```

Create the 1 double once before the for loop and reuse it.

```
XSSFCellStyle cs = fWorkbook.createCellStyle();
cs.setDataFormat(fWorkbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy"));
```

Move the cell style creation and initializing out of the for loop. Create it before the loop and reuse.

```
cell.setCellValue(new Date());
```

Introduce a Date variable and create the Date just once. Again before the for loop.

Comment: Sir, as you suggested I did that it still tacking the same amount of time. After some sort of trial and error I found that, fWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream); is taking all this time. Is there  any way to minimize it?

Comment: What if you replace fileOutputStream with ByteArrayOutputStream? Does it work faster?

Comment: I strongly feel problem is with the size of fileOutputStream. Larger the size of stream more time write operation would take. By first check would be to 'verify that Do i need to save whole data? Am i overwriting the same values.'.

Comment: It is still not working sir, ByteArrayOutputStream is taking similar amount of time as before.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `BufferedOutputStream` around the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: It is still tacking the same amount of time as before.