# Apache POI is taking extremely large time to write into the Workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to create and save records into **Workbook**.
I have almost **5000+ new records** to be written and saved into the workbook.
But at the time of writing the fileOutputStream into the workbook, the execution basically halts and slowed down.

What I mean to say is, at the time of executing this line:

```
workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
```

it almost stops to process 5000+ records. I validated that it's taking nearly **1 hour** (!) to write in the workbook.

How can I improve the performance and overcome this drawback?? Please suggest...

** *Note*: The rest of the codes are normal *Apache POI* related codes and they are executing fine, no issue, hence I didnot mention all of them. Only I got stuck at the above line.

I found one discussion here: 
[FileOutputStream (Apachhe POI) taking too long time to save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425459/fileoutputstream-apachhe-poi-taking-too-long-time-to-save)

but, it did not help me. I need to save the whole file.

Comment: Have you tries HXSSFWorkbook? It is a streaming variant that basically only keeps the necessary parts in memory.

You just have to call cleanup at the end otherwise there wil be unused files left that cal clutter your hard drive.

Comment: "How can I improve the performance and overcome this drawback?": Give it more resources, mainly memory. `XSSFWokbook.write` needs to write multiple `XML` files (and possibly other files too) into a `ZIP` archive. That takes memory resources. But I am writing much more than 5000 rows successfully using `XSSFWorkbook`.

Comment: I tried with **HSSFWorkbook** too, but it's still taking large amount of time, nearly **45-50** mins to write. @Stefan Helmerichs.

Comment: In my case, the file use to be **.xls** spreadsheet, that is, I can use only *HSSFWorkbook* , not *XSSFWorkbook* . @Axel Richter.

Comment: Then your useable system resources must be very low. I am able filling a `HSSFSheet` from row 1 to row 65,536 within 1 second using maximum heap space of 512 MByte.

Comment: @Stefan Helmerichs, did you mean **SXSSFWorkbook** , streaming version of XSSFWorkbook ?? Can you give example of it ?

Comment: I have improved my answer to be an example for `SXSSFWorkbook` too.

Comment: @Prosenjit yes, sorry, I indeed meant SXSSFWorkbook. I was suggesting that as we try to create excel sheets with a lot of rows and SXSSFWorkbook did reduce the time greatly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One more solution I understand, like, while iterating over the Row and creating cells, **DO NOT** keep declaring `CellStyle` and `sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNumber)` inside the loop, rather declare these 2 only once at the outside of the loop and set the values and style only inside the loop, i.e, `cell.setCellStyle` and `cell.setCellValue`.

Declaring the above 2 everytime while iterating, basically degrades the performance of the POI radically.

Answer (score 4):

Let's have a concrete example we can talk about:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class CreateExcel100000Rows {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

System.out.println("whole program starts " + java.time.LocalDateTime.now());

  try (
   //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx")
   //Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx")
   Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xls")
   ) {

   int rows = 100000;
   if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) rows = 65536;

   Object[][] data = new Object[rows][4];
   data[0] = new Object[] {"Value", "Date", "Formatted value", "Formula"};
   for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
    data[i] = new Object[] {1.23456789*i, new GregorianCalendar(2000, 0, i), 1.23456789*i, "ROUND(A" + (i+1) + ",2)"};
   }

   DataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
   CellStyle dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("DDDD, MMMM, DD, YYYY"));
   CellStyle numberStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   numberStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00 \" Coins\""));

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

   sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 12*256);
   sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 35*256);
   sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 17*256);
   sheet.setColumnWidth(3, 10*256);

   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
     Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (r == 0) cell.setCellValue((String)data[r][c]);
     if (r > 0 && c == 0) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)data[r][c]);
     } else if (r > 0 && c == 1) {
      cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar)data[r][c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
     } else if (r > 0 && c == 2) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)data[r][c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(numberStyle);
     } else if (r > 0 && c == 3) {
      cell.setCellFormula((String)data[r][c]);
     }
    }
   }

System.out.println("write starts " + java.time.LocalDateTime.now());
   workbook.write(fileout);
System.out.println("write ends " + java.time.LocalDateTime.now());

   if (workbook instanceof SXSSFWorkbook) ((SXSSFWorkbook)workbook).dispose();
  }

System.out.println("whole program ends " + java.time.LocalDateTime.now());

 }
}
```

This code creates a `HSSFWorkbook` having the first sheet filled from row 1 to row 65,536 having different kind of cell values in columns `A:D`.

Using `java -Xms256M -Xmx512M`, that is heap space from 256 to 512 MByte, this takes 2 seconds in whole. `HSSFWorkbook.write` takes less than a second.

If you do

```
...
  try (
   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx")
   //Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx")
   //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xls")
   ) {
...
```

This code creates a `XSSFWorkbook` having the first sheet filled from row 1 to row 100,000 having different kind of cell values in columns `A:D`.

Using `java -Xms256M -Xmx512M`, that is heap space from 256 to 512 MByte, this takes 7 seconds in whole. `XSSFWorkbook.write` takes 2 seconds. This can be improved by giving more available heap space.

If you do

```
...
  try (
   //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx")
   Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx")
   //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xls")
   ) {
...
```

This code creates a `SXSSFWorkbook` having the first sheet filled from row 1 to row 100,000 having different kind of cell values in columns `A:D`.

Using `java -Xms256M -Xmx512M`, that is heap space from 256 to 512 MByte, this takes 2 seconds in whole. `SXSSFWorkbook.write` takes less than a second.

Note: Using `SXSSFWorkbook`, `((SXSSFWorkbook)workbook).dispose()` is necessary to get rid of the used temporary files.

Comment: Yes, I tested your code in my local, it's also taking few seconds to create Excel.xls. May be there is any mistake that i'm doing in my own code. I need to check. Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: @Prosenjit: What often gets wrong is creating cell styles. Fonts and data formats for cell styles and cell styles itself must be created on workbook level and then only be applied to cells on sheets using `Cell.setCellStyle`. Some people are creating a new cell style for each cell. That's wrong as `Excel` has limits for the count of unique cell formats/cell styles.

Comment: Yes @Axel Richer , I already checked that, the limit of the **CellStyle** is suppose to **4000** , beyond this, it throws some POIException. Hence I create the CellStyle before looping and then I iterate over the rows to set this CellStyle and Cellvalue to each cell using `cell.setCellStyle` and `cell.setCellValue` .

Comment: @Axel Richter, I am using SXSSFWorkbook and writing the output directly to the HTTPResponse. It was all working fine for years until last week. One fine day, it started to take huge time to write the content to the HTTP Outputstream. There were no updates or changes done, it all happened overnight. This consistently happened in all the environments. We are clueless on why this happened. We are using 3.9 version of poi and poi-ooxml.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *merged cells*, this answer might be helpful.

I once had 3000+ records and it took 10 minutes to generate the output xlsx.

After using a Java profiler, I found that
`org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet#getMergedRegion`
took most of the time.

Based on my data set, I found this method grows in O(n^2) (n is the count of records), which explains why it works for small records set(less than 1K) but takes a lot of time for large records set.

I checked the template and output, it had a lot of merged cells generated by `jx:each`:

```
Excel headers
| A | B | C |
|   headers |
`jx:each` cells
| a |   b   | <- merged 
| a |   b   |
...
|   footers |
```

So I unmerged the cells in `jx:each` template, and it takes less than 1 second now.